# Kotlin Compose Preview reference unresolved

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, preview, gradle-dependencies

I am working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project for Android and Desktop using Compose and have the Compose Multiplatform IDE Support plugin installed.

What I am trying to do is add the `@Preview` annotation so I can get a preview of the composables that I'm working on. I tried following this guide to implement that:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/studio

I want to have my shared Compose classes in the module `shared-ui`, so I added the following dependencies to the `build.gradle.kts` in that module:

```
dependencies {
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.3.2")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.3.2")
}
```

However, even after a synchronization, when I try to use or import the `@Preview` annotation in my class (`shared-ui/src/commonMain/kotlin/.../MyScreen.kt`), I get this error:

```
Unresolved reference: preview
```

That happens twice: Once in the import statement, where the final word `Preview` is in red, and once in the annotation, where it is also the word `Preview` that is in red:

```
[...]
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
[...]

@Preview
@Composable
[...]
```

Incidentally, I also tried the quick fix option that Android Studio offered me there: "Add dependency on androidx.compose.ui.ui-tooling-preview and import". What that does is add the dependencies exactly where I added them (provided I remove them first, otherwise it does nothing), which apparently means that Android Studio agrees with me that this is where the dependencies should go.

Which brings me to my ultimate question: Why does this not work? What am I doing wrong? Based on my understanding, this should work. But it doesn't. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm still having this problem, have a look at this https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/tree/master/examples/todoapp

they somehow can use @Preview in `commonMain`, however still not in `androidMain`. i tried to copy the setup over but to no avail. 

however if i remove this dependency 
```
val desktopMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.desktop.common)
            }
        }
```
the @Preview reference is gone. it still doesn't work for me

Comment: @DerekZhu Did you find a solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution for the problem yet?

Comment: I am able to preview the ui in androidMain but not in commonMain

Comment: same here, anyone having a solution yet?